# Low Resolution Mode in macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, resolution, monterey

I routinely run Windows on Virtual Box on my iMac.

I have just updated to macOS Monterey, and have also updated Virtual Box.

When I started Windows this morning, I found that virtual machine uses full retina resolution on my iMac. In the past I could solve this by going to the virtual machine application in Finder, going to Get Info, and turning on the `Always Run in Low Resolution` setting.

This setting appears to have disappeared. How can I set an application to Low Resolution mode?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It didn't work with XCode for me, I had to open it with admin rights. I did this in the terminal with the nano editor: `sudo nano /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources/VirtualBoxVM.app/Contents/Info.plist` and edited to `<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>          <false/>`

Comment: I just ran into the same problem and need to run Audacity in low resolution. Otherwise it's just a pain in the a**...
I just installed Xcode. Unfortunately I don't know anything about that kind of stuff. Could someone try to explain how to do this for noobs, step by step?
Thanks!

Comment: @all_vibes_welcome Have you checked my answer below? That might help.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I have found a temporary solution, which involves changing the `info.plist` file inside the application.

1. Using XCode, open up:

   `/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources/VirtualBoxVM.app/Contents/Info.plist`
2. Change `High Resolution Capable` to `NO`
3. Save

I found that I had to change the file permissions to allow the changes to be saved.

I’m not very familiar with the `PListBuddy` shell program, but the following also seems to work:

This displays the current settings:

```sh
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy \
    -c 'print NSHighResolutionCapable' \
    /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources/VirtualBoxVM.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

This changes the setting:

```sh
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy \
    -c 'set NSHighResolutionCapable false' \
    /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources/VirtualBoxVM.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

- The `sudo` is required to grant permissions to make changes.
- The  `\` at the end of each line allows it to be continued on the next.
- The `-c ' … '` part is the actual command, which you could also use interactively.

As you see, the application is `VirtualBoxVM.app`, which is unusual in that it is an app within an app. The normal location for the `Info.plist` file is something like `/Applications/something.app/Contents/Info.plist` .

I had to re-install Virtual Box, so I had to try this in earnest, and it worked for me.

I’m still looking for a better solution, though.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Manngo,

You can edit the Info.plist file directly and save it.
Make sure VirtualBox isn't running, then

```
sudo vim /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources/VirtualBoxVM.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

change

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>          <true/>
```

to

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>          <false/>
```

and save the file.